# What is the usage of "of" in "parable of the ant"

Tags: prepositions

If I say "parable of the ant", is the "of" means "about"?

Comment: "Does _of_ mean _about_?" Yes, it does.

Answer (score 1):

"Of" implies a sort of ownership or direct connection.  You might say "The fall of Rome" or "The collapse of the USSR".

In this case it's specifically *the* parable of *the* ant.  It's not *a* parable of *an* ant, but it would be acceptable to say "A parable about an ant".

The former is saying that there's a specific well-known parable about a specific ant that we're talking about, whereas the latter is discussing something in more general terms.